# Django resolve with GET parameters — raises Resolver404()

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I need to test if redirecting to a url will result in a 404 error.
Following example in django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#resolve

I managed to get the following to work. So if the `redirect_url` raises a 404, we redirect the user to homepage.

```
redirect_url = '/blog/hello-world'

view, args, kwargs = resolve()
kwargs['request'] = request
try:
    view(*args, **kwargs)
except Http404:
    self.message_user(...)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

However I need to test if the `redirect_url` with a GET parameter of `?edit` also raise 404. As the 'edit' flag is used to return a different queryset. e.g.

```
    if 'edit' in request.GET:
        qs = qs.drafts()
    else:
        qs = qs.public()
```

And I changed my original code:

```
redirect_url = '%s?edit' % redirect_url
[...]
```

However this raise **Resolver404**.

Full stacktrace here: http://dpaste.com/1DQHH7Q

Now my question is how can I test for **HTTP404** error with GET parameters?

The path `blog/2015/07/14/sky-limit-only-those-who-arent-afraid-fly/?edit` is valid, when I go the url in the browser.. it works as expected.

A dirty solution is to do this:

```
 from django.test.client import Client

 client = Client()
 resp = client.get(redirect_url)
 if not resp.status_code == 404:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
```

I really don't want to use this.

Answer (score 1):

The `resolve()` method takes the url without the GET parameters. You could try replacing `request.GET`.

```
redirect_url = '/blog/hello-world'
view, args, kwargs = resolve()
request.GET = {'edit': ''}
kwargs['request'] = request
try:
    view(*args, **kwargs)
except Http404:
    self.message_user(...)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Note that `request` is the request object for your current view, so be careful be careful if you need the actual `request.GET` data.